# How Can I Write a Proper JUnit Test for this code?

Tags: java, junit, greatest-common-divisor

I'm new to programming.  I have to write a JUnit test for this program to find the GCD, shown here :

```
public class CoprimeNumbersTest {


/**
 * Given two integers, this returns true if they are relatively prime and  false if they are not. Based upon the first
 * webpage I found ({@link "https://primes.utm.edu/notes/faq/negative_primes.html"}), the primality of negative
 * numbers is up for debate. This method will not treat negatives differently.
 *
 * @param a First integer to be tested
 * @param b Second integer to be tested
 * @return True when the greatest common divisor of these numbers is 1; false otherwise.
 */
public boolean isCoprime(int a, int b) {
  // Continue using Euclid's algorithm until we find a common divisor
  while (b != 0) {
// Remember b's value
int temp = b;
// Set b to the remainder of dividing a by b (e.g., a mod b).
b = a % b;
// Set a equal to b's old value.
a = temp;
  }
   // The gcd is the value in a. If this is 1 the numbers are coprime.
   if (a == 1) {
return true;
     }
  // When they are not 1, they have a common divisor.
  else {
return false;
  }
}
}
```

This is what I could come up with:

```
public class CoPrimetest {

    @Test
    public void testing() { 
        assetEquals(1, GCDFinder.CoprimeNumbersTest);
    }

}
```

Are there any approaches that I am missing that can help to improve my code?

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson `public class CoPrimetest` vs `public class CoprimeNumbersTest`

Comment: @BrandonIbbotson and it seems they are not in the same class

Comment: @Dan - What is `GCDFinder`, actually `assetEquals(1, GCDFinder.CoprimeNumbersTest);` doesn't make sense to me. Also its suppose to be `assertEquals` (r)

Comment: @dan have a look at https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_basic_usage.htm

Comment: Ah, the formatting made it hard to notice. The class name wasn't in the code block so I assumed they were continuous. Anyway, if it's not test code, don't put `Test` on the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually call your method, just like in normal code. (The following code is not tested, I don't know if 1 and 1 are actually co-prime.)

```
public class CoPrimetest {

    @Test
    public void testing() { 
       CoprimeNumbersTest instance = new CoprimeNumbersTest();
       boolean result = instance.isCoprime( 1, 1 );
       boolean expected = true;
       assertEquals( expected, result );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this fix fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

A sample test method to write against the `isCoprime` method in your `CoprimeNumbersTest` class could be

```
@org.junit.Test
public void isCoprime() throws Exception {
    org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(true, new CoprimeNumbersTest().isCoprime(3,4)); 
}
```

Since the return type of method is `boolean`, you can either assert it equal to either `true` or `false`.

Would suggest, try to dry run `isCoprime` method with these inputs `(3,4)` and figure out what all statements have been covered. Based on the that infer what inputs if you would provide would cover the remaining of the statements. That should help to cover the code with Unit Tests.

---

On a side note, try renaming your classes to practice a better naming convention, something like `GreatestCommonDivisor.java` and `GreatestCommonDivisorTest.java` linking them as well.